# Using axios.all with an instance for POST requests

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm currently building an app that requires the submission of several POST requests. I want to use [`axios.all`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosalliterable) to achieve this, since I can then verify each request was successful before continuing.

The app uses an axios instance, declared as `client`. However, I'm having two issues:

- `client` does not have access to the `.all` iteration method
- Adding `client.post` requests to an array instantly executes them

Here's an example of the code I am working with:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL
})

let requests = []

for (let section of {{ some data }}) {
  requests.push(client.post('response_endpoint', section.responses))
}

client.all(requests)
```

Is there any way I can make this work, or will I need to rethink my method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `Promise.all()` instead `axios.all()`

Comment: I never knew axios had an `all` helper, and as [seen here](https://github.com/axios/axios/commit/c43f2b9710549626eba63916b3c3e7d2c100e402#diff-7c5e8f9cd43daae0cf976ad5dd3b5a00R133) it's really just an alias for `Promise.all`, which begs the question why have it there in the first place.  My assumption is that `axios.all` is considered a static method and doesn't transfer over to instances.  Almost seems like a bug for it to not transfer to instances, but the bug should be fixed by removing that useless helper from their api.